# Unable to fix a 'float' object is not callable error

Tags: python

I keep getting the error: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable on this section of code.

```
for data in list:
    latitude = float(data[1])
    longitude = float(data[2])
    distance = ((6371*math.pi)/180)(math.sqrt((-35.276159-latitude)**2+(149.120893-longitude)**2))
    print(distance)
```

When I print the type of latitude and longitude, they both return 'float'.  Any help with what I could be doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have used `float` as a variable in your code

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `data`, `list`, etc.?

Comment: first of all don't name your list object with list variable, and can you give some example what is in (list variable)

Comment: Also don't forget to format your code correctly - at the moment your code doesn't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over your sequence and are calling the `item` `data`; this got you confused that `data` is the sequence.

You are also missing an operator between two expressions in parenthesis: `distance = ((6371 * math.pi) / 180)` **MISSING OPERATOR HERE** `(math.sqrt((-35.276159 - latitude) ** 2 + (149.120893 - longitude) ** 2))` - this corresponds to `(float)(float)` after partial evaluation, which is attempting to call a float.

```
for item in seq:
    latitude = float(item)
    longitude = float(item)
    distance = ((6371 * math.pi) / 180)**2 + (math.sqrt((-35.276159 - latitude) ** 2 + (149.120893 - longitude) ** 2))
    print(distance)
```

#### Note:

Please do not use python keywords (`list`) to name variables.

Comment: why will that lead to `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`. See @Rakesh's comment, that seems much more probable

Comment: @akshat This answer is correct - (thing1)(thing2) is the syntax for attempting to call thing1 with parameters thing2. Rakesh's comment is incorrect - float has not been used as a variable, it has been used as a function.